# iMessage extension App Icon not showing on iPad

Tags: swift3, ios10, xcode8, imessage

I created an iMessage extension from the XCode 8 beta wizard and added every single icon size to the Assets.xcassets.

Everything looks perfect on XCode and when I run the iMessage extension on any iPhone device (simulator or real device) all my icons are perfect. However, when I run it on any iPad device (simulator or real device) the default placeholder stays there.

I have tried adding the icons from the sample application but the result is the same for iPad

Answer (score 7):

After breaking my head with every single possible solution with the images, filenames, build phases... I ended up looking at the Info.plist of the extension and discovering that there was a key that was conflicting with the Assets.

I am not sure if that key got there from the initial creation of the project with the XCode 8 beta 1 and if it has been resolved afterwards.

In order to fix the issue just remove this key

```
CFBundleIcons~ipad
```

from the Info.plist and your icons will show in your iPad.

Comment: In case anybody has the same problem, I had to remove both `CFBundleIcons` and `CFBundleIcons~ipad` keys to fix the issue